# Problema JAVA input lanza error

Tags: java

practicando un poco de Java me encontré con un ejercicio que me pareció interesante para manejar funciones, el enunciado es bastante largo y está en un libro (por ende me es difícil copiarlo, ademas que le hice una variación) pero básicamente es una matriz de 4 cursos y 3 clases el cual cada uno de los espacios representa cuantos estudiantes hay en la combinación, por ejemplo en el curso 1 clase 2 hay 0 estudiantes, o en el curso 1 clase 1 hay 3 estudiantes.

Tengo una función para agregar estudiantes pero no sé porque me lanza un error, como soy nuevo en Java tal vez estoy cometiendo un error que no lo percibo, el error me corre cuando en las funciones insertar y eliminar pido la clase que el usuario quiere (eliminar|insertar).

La excepción que me corre es la siguiente:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
at Main.Punto_23_Pagina_92.insertar(Punto_23_Pagina_92.java:55)
at Main.Punto_23_Pagina_92.main(Punto_23_Pagina_92.java:25)
```

Adjunto el código del programa, muchas gracias de antemano, estaré pendiente a los comentarios.

```
package Main;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Punto_23_Pagina_92 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner;
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int[][] cursos = new int[4][3];

        for (int i = 0;i<4;i++) {
            for (int i2 = 0;i2<3;i2++) {
                cursos[i][i2] = 0;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("(1) Añadir alumnos - (2) Eliminar alumnos - (3) Alumnos en clase - (4) Salir");
        int opcion = scanner.nextInt();
        char clase = 'D';

        while (opcion != 4) {
            if (opcion == 1) {
                cursos = insertar(cursos);
            } else if (opcion == 2) {
                cursos = eliminar(cursos);
            } else if (opcion == 3) {
                for (int i = 0;i<4;i++) {
                    for (int i2 = 0; i2<3; i2++) {
                        if (i2 == 0) {
                            clase = 'A';
                        } else if (i2 == 1) {
                            clase = 'B';
                        } else if (i2 == 2) {
                            clase = 'C';
                        }
                        System.out.println ("El curso "+i+" de la clase "+ clase +" tiene "+ cursos[i][i2]+" estudiantes" );
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println("(1) Añadir alumnos - (2) Eliminar alumnos - (3) Alumnos en clase - (4) Salir");
            opcion = scanner.nextInt();
        }

    }

    public static int[][] insertar(int[][] cursos){
        Scanner scanner;
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Elige el curso:");
        int curso = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Elige la clase:");
        char clase;
        clase = scanner.nextLine().charAt(0);
        System.out.println("¿Cuantos estudiantes van a ingresar al curso?:");
        int cantidad = scanner.nextInt();
        if (clase == 'A') {
            cursos[curso][0] = cursos[curso][0] + cantidad;
        }else if(clase == 'B') {
            cursos[curso][1] = cursos[curso][1] + cantidad;
        }else if (clase == 'C') {
            cursos[curso][2] = cursos[curso][2] + cantidad;
        }
        return cursos;

    }

    public static int[][] eliminar(int[][] cursos){
        Scanner scanner;
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Elige el curso:");
        int curso = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Elige la clase:");
        char clase = scanner.nextLine().charAt(0);
        System.out.println("¿Cuantos estudiantes van a salir del curso?:");
        int cantidad = scanner.nextInt();
        if (clase == 'A') {
            if (cursos[curso][0] - cantidad >= 0) {
            cursos[curso][0] = cursos[curso][0] - cantidad;
            } else {
                System.out.println("No puedes quitar estudiantes que no existen");
            }
        }else if(clase == 'B') {
            if (cursos[curso][1] - cantidad >= 0) {
                cursos[curso][1] = cursos[curso][1] - cantidad;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("No puedes quitar estudiantes que no existen");
                }
        }else if (clase == 'C') {
            if (cursos[curso][2] - cantidad >= 0) {
                cursos[curso][2] = cursos[curso][2] - cantidad;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("No puedes quitar estudiantes que no existen");
                }
        }
        return cursos;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema del que hablas se genera debido a un mal uso del método `nextLine()` Para leer valores tipo char por consola, debes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
char clase = scanner.next().charAt(0);
```

Modifica tus métodos eliminar e insertar, y eso solucionará tu problema. Si te fue de ayuda, marca la respuesta como válida para ayudar a otras personas con un problema parecido al tuyo. Suerte!

Comment: Sí, me sirvió perfecto pero esque en otro programa ya lo había hecho con nextLine() y en ese programa me sirvió era para un char también, ¿por qué aqui cambia? ---- Muchas gracias por tu respuesta!!!

Comment: Porque nextLine es para leer datos de tipo STRING, asi como nextInt es para leer datos de tipo Integer.